# Importing a text CSV file within zip file from ftp url causes bound error (BoundsError)

Tags: zip, julia

```
using HTTP, ZipFile, CSV
datafile="ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/DVS/natality/Nat2018ps.zip"

function rzip(datafile)
    dat = HTTP.get(datafile)
    r = ZipFile.Reader(IOBuffer(dat.body))
    f  = r.files[1]
    CSV.read(f, delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true) 
end
```

The function `rzip` reads zipfile and txt file witin it, uses `CSV` to create dataframe and then reads it into table.

When running it the following error is seen:

```
julia> rzip(datafile)
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 16-element Array{UInt64,1} at index [-9223372036854775807]
```

Comment: Hey, it may be helpful to post the error in your question!

Comment: BoundsError: attempt to access 16-element Array{UInt64,1} at index [-9223372036854775807]
getindex at array.jl:744 [inlined]
getindex at multidimensional.jl:486 [inlined]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ZipFile.Reader` stream is not a random-access stream so it does not work correctly in the multi-threaded that has been recently introduced in `CSV.jl`
Hence you need to use the `threaded=false` option.

```
using HTTP, ZipFile, CSV
datafile="ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Datasets/DVS/natality/Nat2018ps.zip"
dat = HTTP.get(datafile)
r = ZipFile.Reader(IOBuffer(dat.body))
f  = r.files[1]
df = CSV.read(f, delim=' ', ignorerepeated=true, threaded=false)
```

Now just to show that it works:

```
julia> df
25918×56 DataFrames.DataFrame. Omitted printing of 51 columns  
│ Row   │ 201801 │ 04272GU │ 010311 │ 1     │ 20083US │
│       │ Int64  │ String  │ Int64  │ Int64 │ String  │
├───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼───────┼─────────┤
│ 1     │ 201801 │ 05592GU │ 10311  │ 1     │ 35116FM │
│ 2     │ 201801 │ 11362GU │ 10311  │ 1     │ 22083US │        
⋮
│ 25916 │ 201808 │ 01001PR │ 31371  │ 2     │ 22083US │        
│ 25917 │ 201811 │ 00495PR │ 21311  │ 1     │ 19072US │        
│ 25918 │ 201806 │ 10221PR │ 127211 │ 1     │ 19072US │
```

Comment: Thanks although some of the imported raws are note correct, but that is topic for another day! I think it has to do with fwf importing. CSV.read does not specify the exact character starting point and width and hence blank spaces are misrepresented in table. don't know how to fix it. Jaimin

Comment: maybe make another qustion witth it since this is a different issue.